# Include translations in PrestaShop module

Tags: module, prestashop, translation

For my PrestaShop module I have a Dutch translation available. I would like to include this translation into the module, so that upon installing it, the language is integrated right away.

In other words, editing theme folders and managing things in the backoffice wouldn't be necessary.

Keep in mind that the first language has to be English. So Dutch would be the extra language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to translate the module with translation editor of PrestaShop, in backoffice select "Localization > Translation", select "Translate modules" and after select "Core", at last select the language (Dutch in your case)

Search your module name, translate all the string, save. PrestaShop create a new file in `translation` folder of your module most probably named `de.php`.

Done :). When you give your module to someone (or sell it) the translations are already included ;)